# What to understand before reading Bott and Tu

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, book-recommendation, differential-forms, advice

After working through a small part of Bott and Tu's book "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology" I've found that the topics really interest me. However, it seems that maybe I lack some background to really be able to appreciate the material. For reference, I've taken a year of analysis (standard analysis on $\mathbb{R}$ and abstract measure theory) and algebra (undergrad level) at a good uni. I've also taken  grad algebraic topology (chapters 1,2 of Hatcher) and grad algebra (dummit and foote chapters 1-12 and ch 15).

My question is, how much differential topology do I need for Bott-Tu? The intro stuff on forms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is all fine, and I've read bits and pieces of smooth manifolds books. I often find, however, that I sometimes easily get confused on stuff like orientation and forms on manifolds (especially when Bott-Tu define integration along a fiber). It also doesn't help that Bott-Tu don't have many exercises for me to practice. Am I mature enough to read Bott-Tu or do I need more background? Is Bott-Tu regarded as a good bok? Do you have any advice for reading the book? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Bott-Tu is regarded as a good book indeed. I suggest to take a course on differential geometry before reading it. You need to feel comfortable with manifolds and vector bundles.

Comment: I found that already having a course on de Rham cohomology helped me to read the first chapters, since their coverage is rather terse. Later on they talk about spectral sequences, and I think by that point it's probably best if you've been introduced to them through a more user-friendly source, but you can understand the first chapters without it.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain I see. I probably will not take a differential geometry or differential topology class until next semester, in that case what should I do if I would like to read Bott-Tu? Should I continue to read Bott-Tu and simply look up the stuff I don't understand? Or should I focus on more manifolds and vector bundles stuff (such as from Lee's Smooth Manifolds book)? Thank you for your help :) Also, how do people read Bott-Tu if it doesn't have exercises?

Comment: @William If I haven't had a course dealing with de Rham cohomology yet, what would you recommend that I do? I probably won't get to the spectral sequences chapter in Bott-Tu for quite some time, but I definitely want to at least understand the Thom and Euler class stuff from section 1. Should I keep reading Bott-Tu and just look up stuff if I'm confused? When you were reading Bott-Tu did you do many of the exercises? Thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: @confusedStudent4455 I don't know but if I have to give a suggestion, then I would pick up a good geometry book and study it up to De Rham's theorem (I've never used Lee's book but I'd say chapters 1-11 except 6-7 would do) then go back to Bott-Tu and read it. Notice that if you get to chap 11 of Lee the first 50 pages of Bott-Tu would be almost done.
Moreover those are all foundations of differential geometry that you will need to understand at a certain point if you want to do geometry.

Comment: Warlock made some really good suggestions. My suggestion is if you specifically want to learn de Rham cohomology, I found Madsen and Tornehave's "From Calculus To Cohomology" to be a really great (albeit expensive) hands-on introduction.

Comment: @WarlockofFiretopMountain Thank you! I think I will definitely move to reading Lee's book to gain some intimacy with manifolds and then move to Bott-Tu, since ultimately I am interested in differential geometry.

Comment: @William I took a look at this book and it looks very good, I will definitely keep this on my desk; thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would definitely need some basic understanding of manifolds, but I don't think you will need too much. I think you will need definitions, closed submanifolds, immersions/submersions, tangent and cotangent bundles, vector fields and differential forms. Though the book defines differential forms, it chooses algebraic approach. So it would be difficult to read if you don't know what differential forms really are. But you don't need to read the whole book on manifolds. If you will need some extra-stuff, you can always look it up.

You can also refer to this [book by Loring Tu](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441973990) and [notes by Sossinsky](http://ium.mccme.ru/postscript/f09/TOP-2.pdf).

Comment: Would it be okay to learn the basics of what you suggested (closed submanifolds, immersions/submertions,..., differential forms) concurrently as I read Bott-Tu? Also, is Bott-Tu aimed at someone with my background or do I need more? Thank you :)